# Trying to Print With Python (and PIL)

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, printing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to send an image to a printer to print using a Python script. I'm not overly experienced in the language and took a few tips from a few other people, and I'm currently having an issue in that I keep getting an error saying a file in PIL is missing. Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import socket
import sys
from threading import Thread

def print_bcard(HOST):
    print 'Printing business card'
    card_pic = Image.open("/home/nao/recordings/cameras/bcard.jpg")
    HOST = '192.168.0.38'
    PORT = 9100  
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    f = open(str(card_pic), 'rb')  #open in binary
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        s.send(l)
        l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

    s.close()

print_bcard('192.168.0.38')
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:'<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile 
image mode=RGB size=4032x2268 at 0x30C8D50>'
```

Does anyone know what's going on, or if not, a different way of accessing the photo without using PIL? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the issue is that you are opening the image with PIL here:
`card_pic = Image.open("/home/nao/recordings/cameras/bcard.jpg")`
than trying open the file here:
`f = open(str(card_pic), 'rb')  #open in binary`
but `str(card_pic)` is trying to turn the PIL image object into a string, it does not give you back the filename.
try this line instead:
`f = open("/home/nao/recordings/cameras/bcard.jpg", 'rb')`

Comment: exactly. `<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile 
image mode=RGB size=4032x2268 at 0x30C8D50>` is not a valid filename.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the content of a file then you just pass the filename. Instead you're loading it into a PIL `Image` and then passing the image to the file `open()` function which doesn't make any kind of sense.

Try:

```
with open("/home/nao/recordings/cameras/bcard.jpg", 'rb') as f:
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        s.send(l)
        l = f.read(1024)
```